# Is there a way to avoid certain area types?

Tags: temple-run-2

I was wondering if there was a way to predict what type of area will come up based on the choices I make at junctions. If I turn right, will I go into the jungle? Will left take me into the mine?

I've been able to see some things past the upcoming turns, such as powerups and traps. Are there visual clues that will tell me when there are area changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. I tried going only left/right side. But they will come up randomly.

You can only see a little portion of upcoming area. Sometimes it is possible to see power ups and traps as you mentioned, but it's not possible to guess area change with this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least people claim that partially it's possible, and from my observations it's like that. You can choose between the waterslide and the mine. If you always turn left (when 2 choices), you get waterslide, if you always turn right, you get the mine.

It's quite hard to control that by the highest speeds, especially when on sprint or bolt run!